# Fetching data from api promise in react API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I fetch data from the Company API by using a specific proxy in package.json.

this is my code:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState({
        loading: false,
        data: null,
        error: false,
    });

    const apiLink = 'https://example.com/api/checkout/products/';

    useEffect(() => {
        setProducts({
            loading: true,
            data: null,
            error: false,
        });

        fetch(apiLink, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "categories": [
                        "13", "14", "4", "8"
                    ]
                })
            })
            .then(response => {
                response.json().then(data => console.log(data.products))
            })
    }, [apiLink])
```

but when I console.log() the data it appear like that in console:

```
Promise {<pending>}
   [[Prototype]]: Promise
   [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
   [[PromiseResult]]: Object
```

and inside the [[PromiseResult]] There is the information I need to deal with it. Like: products

how can i access to this products and loop its in my page. please i need help.

because when i access to products like that:

```
console.log(products.data.products)
```

i have undefined in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async/await in the useEffect

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const init = async () => {
    setProducts({
      loading: true,
      data: null,
      error: false,
    });

    try {
      const response = await fetch(apiLink, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          categories: ["13", "14", "4", "8"],
        }),
      });
      response = await response.json();
      // set your state after this
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  init();
}, [apiLink]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in [MDN: Uploading JSON data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data), after receiving data from API you should handle each operation in a separate `.then` process.

```js
fetch(apiLink, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "categories": [
       "13", "14", "4", "8"
    ]
  })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data.products))
```

Comment: bro but i need to set the products in setProducts() 
`
.then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => 
                setProducts({
                    loading: false,
                    data: data.products,
                    error: false
                })    
            )
`

when i map it like that 
`
content = products.data.products.map(product => {
            console.log(product)
        })
`
i get error like that TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: You need not specify "data.products" while mapping..You Should map like this --- content = products.map(product => console.log(product)

Comment: Okay, so now the question is something different. In the line `.then(data => console.log(data.products))` what is the result? What does it log? Is it an Array of objects?

Comment: can you print the json() response only to know what data shape you have `then(response =>console.log( response.json()))`

Answer (score 0):

the promise is needed only in the fetch() method since it is a deferred computation, after that you can use any method to process your data

```js
fetch(apiLink, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "categories": [
       "13", "14", "4", "8"
    ]
  })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.catch(x=>console.log(x)).map(x=>console.log(x.products))
```

you can learn more about promises in: https://learnjsx.com/category/2/posts/es6-promise